# Spells (debuffs) that increase damage from other spells

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Motivation: I am playing a "solo" adventure with a wizard and a healbot cleric NPC/DMPC. A lot of times it would be more helpful if the cleric increased the damage output instead of healing/buffing; I am inclined not to do that by direct damage as the player enjoys blasting things.

I tried looking for a spell that increases spell damage, either by buffing the wizard or debuffing the enemies but couldn't find any. Ideally I want to directly increase damage taken (for example compared to increasing dps by increasing hit change).

I thought about creating a custom spell, perhaps basing it on the Maximized metamagic e.g. "the next spell of the target is casted as if it was maximized assuming that it is not higher than the spell slot you used for this spell-2" but I'm not sure about the balance.

Comment: Not quite what you are looking for, but [Channel The Gift](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/channel-the-gift) would be a good aid.

Comment: If you are creating spells, try the "Weakness to <Element>" line similar to The Elder Scrolls video games. "Weakness to fire makes all fire damage sources do half against as much damage as they would have otherwise." +50%

Comment: @SurrealAnalysis yeah, channel the gift sounds like a must have; thanks!

Comment: @Red_Shadow I LOVE this idea! will provide a nice boost and cannot be used on everything (immune to <element> creatures should resist the debuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clerics have a few items in their inventory to assist allies like foxes cunning, bull's strength, Cat's grace, Spell resistance, superior Spell resistance, and others.  These are fixed benefits, some are defensive others like Foxes Cunning can increase a casters DC. Effective debuffing spells tend to fall in the Arcane caster catagory like Lower Spell resistance.  Debuffing enemies and augmenting damage are Arcane not Divine roles.

What you are talking about creating a spell with Maximize Metamagic you could also try with Heighten Spell.  I am not sure if your character is into crafting, but you can craft metamagic rods which can apply a number of uses of a feat. there are other items that can be crafted also.

Aside from what the Cleric can do there are other things that the character can do themselves to improve their casting.  They can take feats like Practiced Spellcaster found in Complete Arccane, Improved Caster Level from NBoF.  They can get items like Ring of Arcane Power or maybe Ioun Stones.  You could also look into Words of Power, Archtypes, and Bloodlines.

Comment: "Ideally I want to directly increase damage taken (for example compared to increasing dps by increasing hit change)." All your suggestions involve the Cleric increasing the hit chance, not the damage taken.

Comment: You are right, Clerics are limited in what they can do. Bull's Strength can directly increase melee damage, but not spell damage. Heighten Spell can add dice to the damage and reduce the opponents chance of saving. Like I was pointing out, what you are asking is really outside of the Cleric's role as designed. Your Custom creation is not a bad idea as far as opening a possiblity. You are trying to cross into Arcane functionality with a Cleric. The answer remains accurate, what you are asking for is not part of the Cleric role.

Comment: (to avoid confusion: I'm not miniman) As I said that I **ideally** want to directly increase damage taken the answer is valid; after all, if someone asks for X to do Y, saying that you can't do Y with X is a valid answer. I just started playing pathfinder so I appreciate the feedback; I'd rather not add arcane functionalities to the cleric so, for now, I'll just wait and see if there's an actual need to do it.